# How to access Anaconda environment variables?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just saved an environment variable (`DB_PWD`) for my Anaconda root environment in `Anaconda2/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.bat` and `Anaconda2/etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.bat` per these [instructions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).

I then restarted iPython and entered:

```
import os
print os.environ.keys()
```

but I did not see my environment variable `DB_PWD`. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate your virtualenv (anaconda virtualenv) before running Python.

Open a MS-DOS console, and run:

```
Anaconda2/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars
```

Then you can try:

```
import os
print os.environ.keys()
```

It should work.